# Variable Returning Undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, meteor

I'm trying to do a very simple function to store the value of a text element. For some reason, when I console.log the variable that stores the text of the element, I receive the value "Undefined". Please let me know why I may be receiving this response. Thanks.

```
<div class="plItem">
    <a class="audiobuy">BUY</a>
    <a id="plNum5">5</a>
    <a class="plTitle5">Song </a>
    <span class="plLength">0:59</span>
</div>
</li>

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    $(function() {
        // Define Audio
        song = new Audio('waitforme.mp3');

       // Define Play
       play = $('#playicon');

       trackNum = $('#plNum5').text();

       $('#playicon').on("click", function() {
           song.play();
       })
    });
}
```

Comment: where are you writing `console.log`?

Comment: In the developer tools console.

Comment: frankly, i think your question is irrelevant: I assume your data eventually will come from the database, that means you will need to build a template that will display the HTML with those values, then this template will be applied to  each element in your collection. 
What you really need to do then is attach a event to the template to grab the object that was clicked and you;ll get the object content there. You should not need any JQuery into your Meteor code.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the answer to this question still -- related to Jquery here...not Meteor & templating. Unless there are some compatibility issues that might be causing this error...

Comment: add console.log statements to your code, use the Chrome debugger... the console itself may not work if the code is out of scope.

Comment: Why does the console.log statement have to be in the code? Why can't we run console.log from the console? It's inside the scope of the Meteor.isClient. Do Jquery functions have to be within the scope of an event to work?

Comment: We need to know where you are seeing the variable being `undefined`. None of the code you are showing is using `trackNum`. Is `trackNum` global? if not you won't be able to console.log it directly from the javascript console

Comment: Ok so the issue was that I needed to define Template.Music.Events.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I needed to use `Meteor.Template.Events { }`, because I was accessing the DOM before the template was finished rendering, and the Meteor standard syntax for Events: `'click #playicon': function(){`.